# Loop until (py)

Tags: python

```
amount_of_names = int(input("Input amount of players: "))
names = []

for counter in range(amount_of_names):
  name = str(input("Input players first name: "))
  names.append(name)
#print (names)
selected_name = str(input("Input your name: "))

while name in names:
  import random 
  names = random.choice(names)
  break
print (names)
```

I am trying to match a name from within the list with "your name" and loop until the names do not match e.g. Bob: Sam (Yes) Sam: Sam (No) - Thanks in advance all

Comment: What do you mean 'clearing during the loop'?

Answer (score 0):

Make a `list`, then add the inputs to it with `append`.

```
AmountOfNames = int(input("Input amount of players: "))
Names = []

for counter in range (0, AmountOfNames):
    RegisteredName = input("Input player {}'s first name: ".format(counter+1))
    Names.append(RegisteredName)

print(Names)
```

Example:

```
Input amount of players: 3
Input player 1's first name: Simon
Input player 2's first name: James
Input player 3's first name: Jacob
['Simon', 'James', 'Jacob']
```

Or you could do something like:

```
>>> names = input("Enter the first names of the players: ").split(", ")
Enter the first names of the players: Simon, James, Jacob
>>> names
['Simon', 'James', 'Jacob']
```

With the above method, if they don't separate them with commas and spaces each time, it will glitch out, so be very careful.

Comment: is that just a hard coded method? im looking for something more dynamic

Comment: @RyanEvans What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: @RyanEvans See the updated answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes! hopefully these answers given will help me thanks a bunch all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
amount_of_names = int(input("Input amount of players: "))
names = []

for counter in range(amount_of_names):
    name = str(input("Input players first names: "))
    names.append(name)

print names
```

Now, `names` list contains `amount_of_names` name

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty array out side of the loop. EG. NameList=[ ] then, inside the loop, for every iteration, add the name to the list useing NameList.append(//name)